# $f(x) * f(y) = f(x-y) + f(x+y)$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

It's a question from a Math Olympiad in Azerbaijan. There is a function $f :Z \rightarrow Z$ and $f(x) * f(y) = f(x-y) + f(x+y)$. If $f(1) = 1$, find $f(100)$

Comment: Does it really say $f(x)=1$?  Then (as Reinstein noted) it does not satisfy $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)f(x-y)$.

Comment: Another point, if $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, then why can't you take $x$ to be $100$?

Comment: oh thanks i made a mistake f(1) = 1

Answer (score 2):

How I would begin (assuming you meant $f(1)=1$): $x=1,y=0$ gives
$$
f(1)\cdot f(0)=f(1)+f(1)\\
f(0)=2
$$
Now $x=1,y=1$ gives
$$
f(1)\cdot f(1)=f(2)+f(0)\\
f(2)=-1
$$
From here, can you find $f(3)$? What about $f(4)$? Can you guess a pattern, and prove that it holds? Or do you have to calculate a hundred different values? Or can you, at least, be clever about which values of $f$ you calculate and get away with much fewer than a hundred calculations to reach $f(100)$?

Comment: Note that even if such a function doesn't exist, that doesn't make me wrong. "Given a function which can't exist, its value at $100$ is $5$" is a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was that the there is **no** sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ for what $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Trouble is, if $a_n$ is the real part of $e^{2in\pi/6}$, the recurrence relation holds.